# Asynchronous MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous

im trying to make an asynchronous connection to a MySQL database to avoid my application from freezing up. I was wondering:

- is this possible?-
- what does the constructor string look like? so far mine is: `Server=...;Database=...;User ID=...;Password=...;Pooling=True`- Do i need to add something enabling asynchronous processing? ("Asynchronous Processing=true" doesnt work)

have you ever done this? ANY help is appreciated. thanks so much!!!

for reference, this is basically what im trying to accomplish (C#):

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con); 
    IAsyncResult iSynch;
    iSynch= cmd.BeginExecuteReader();
    while(!iSynch.IsCompleted){
        print("loading loading loading");
    }
    rdr = cmd.EndExecuteReader(iSynch);
```

Comment: start a different thread using a BackGroundWorker: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: @davek i dont think i can use BackGroundWorker because it is windows-specific right? (im working with unity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the code you're proposing would still freeze your application until the processing is done.

The way to do this is to spawn a second thread that does the querying and the ui update (through `Invoke`), leaving the first thread free to process windows messages.